# Hide default value unless triggered

Tags: javascript

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lj4ni.png) I have 2 dates, Start date and End date.
If End date is 1/1/2018 then Start day by default is always 1 "day" greater than End day i.e. 1/2/2017 in this case. I am trying to set the input as Start date to be invisible but automatically +1 day of End date. However, the user can change it to any date they want. I am trying to hide the field unless a value has been selected.

Here is what i tried so far.

I set the labels for date. I tried setting type ="hidden" but i am not really trying to hide the field but only hide the input until it has been selected. The user should still be able to run the page without start date being selected.

```
<label3>Start of Lease </label3> <input  id="startDate"  type="date" ><br/>
        </br>
        <label3>End of Lease</label3>  <input id="endDate" onchange="PopulateRentPaymentDates()" type="date" > <br/>
        </td>
```

Here, i am setting it up to where if a user hasn't selected the date, it will take End date + 1.

```
 if (document.getElementById("startDate"))
    stDate = document.getElementById("startDate").value;
else stDate = document.getElementById("startDate").value = getCurrentDay(sDate);
```

This is my calculation for Start date.

```
var endDate = document.getElementById("endDate").value;
if (endDate){
var etDate = new Date(endDate);
var eDay = etDate.getUTCDate()+1;
var eMonth = etDate.getUTCMonth()+1;
var eYear = etDate.getUTCFullYear()-1;
var sDate = eYear + "-" + eMonth + "-" + eDay;


        if (stDate == null)
    {
        sDate.setMonth(sDate.getDay() - parseInt(paymentDays));
    }
```

This is the output i am trying to hide. This code works with calculation but i am trying to hide the output unless a user has actually selected the date. Is there a way to make the output invisible in any way? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
if (document.getElementById("startDate"))
        document.getElementById("startDate").value = getCurrentDay(sDate);
```

Comment: So just to clarify you want to hide the start input until the start input is selected? If so how do you envision it being selected if it's hidden? Or do you mean that the start input should be hidden until the end input is selected?

Comment: If it's the latter and you want to only display the start input once the end input has been selected, you can do this by setting the display style for the start input to none, and then when the end input is selected remove the display style. You could also do the same using the hidden attribute. Let me know if that's kind of what you had in mind?

Comment: @JasonAnderson Hello Jason. Yes. I am trying to hide the start input until it has been selected. Just the input itself and not the entire label. I tried using type = "hidden" but that will hide the label itself. What i am trying to do is print the values starting on Start date however, if someone doesn't know the start date, then the system will still print the values because by default the values are always end date +1 day.

Comment: @JasonAnderson I added an image of the project. A user should be able to print the results based on end date because start date is optional. The last line of code where it's giving the output is where i am having an issue because i want to set the start date as above however, not display it.

Comment: Just a nitpick, but try selecting a date like `March 31st` as your "end date" and your "start date" would end up as `March 32nd`... You should do `etDate.setUTCDate(etDate.getUTCDate()+1)` or similar, although keep in mind that you may still have issues if your "end date" is `February 29th`.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Yes. The code is doing that right now. The issue is not with setting the date but displaying it. I just need to hide the dates but still set it unless a user selects it then only display it.

Comment: Eh... I'd disagree, personally. If some part of it is broken, might as well fix it now, right?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Yes. I have a different function handling the dates and this is a part of it. But, you're right, if the year is a leap year it is an issue as far as calculation is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this could be an issue with your CSS. The following is an example of the input being hidden until an end date is selected.

HTML

```
<label3>Start of Lease </label3> 
<input  id="startDate"  type="date" hidden >
<br/>

<label3>End of Lease</label3>  
<input id="endDate" type="date" >
```

JavaScript

```
document.getElementById ("endDate").addEventListener ("change", populateRentPaymentDates, false);

function populateRentPaymentDates(){
    var endDate = document.getElementById("endDate").value;

  if (endDate == ""){
    return;
  }

  // Calculate your start date here
  var startDate = endDate;

  updateStartDate(startDate);
  displayStartDate();
}

function updateStartDate(startDate){
    document.getElementById("startDate").value = startDate;
}

function displayStartDate(){
    document.getElementById("startDate").removeAttribute("hidden");
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6fg6u1a2/3/

Let me know if this is what you kind of had in mind?

Comment: I would recommend using disabled with a title(Please select end of lease first) instead of hidden on the first input field.

Comment: And the eventlistener on enddate needs to be change :) Than it should work

Comment: If you change those things I'll give you an upvote :)

Comment: Good points Domenik, I've updated the example to reflect these changes

Comment: My bad I forgot to update the link. Just updated this to the next revision

Comment: @DomenikReitzner I am not trying to disable the field but make the values invisible. I don't know if that is even possible. I will see if i can add a link here to explain better. But thank you for your help.

Comment: @ace I've updated the code example to hide the input. Although I would have to agree with Domenik that disabling the field would make it clearer to understand from the users perspective. That said I don't know all of the use cases but still either way works.